# Insights and exception mishandling : basic command-line game in Python

Tags: python, project

I am a beginner Python programmer (Python 3) and I just made my first real working program. I encounter an issue with the try: except: part (ln 63), I can't manage to trigger the range_error condition in the usr_input() function. I'm probably not using exceptions the right way.

```py
from random import randint

def gen_num():
    magic_num = randint(1,100)
    return magic_num

def usr_input(range_error = False):
    if range_error == True: # If number is out of range, displays additionnal warning message
        print("Make sure you enter a number between 1 and 100 !")
    usr_num_guess = input("Please enter an integer between 1 and 100 : ")
    return int(usr_num_guess)

def play_again():
    # We ask the user to choose if he wants to play again or not (yes / no)
    yes = set(['yes','y','ye','yeah',''])
    no = set(['no','n'])

    usr_choice = input("Do you wish t play again ? (Y/n):").lower()
    if usr_choice in yes:
        return True
    elif usr_choice in no:
        return False
    else:
        sys.stdout.write("Please write 'yes' or 'no'")

def player_level_initialize():
    # Setting up the user's desired level
    easy_level = set(['easy',1])
    med_level = set(['medium','med',2,''])
    hard_level = set(['hard','difficult',3])

    level_choice = input("Please select your level (easy,MED,hard) :").lower()

    if (level_choice in easy_level):
        return "easy"
    elif (level_choice in med_level):
        return "med"
    elif (level_choice in hard_level):
        return "hard"
    else:
        sys.stdout.write("Please write 'easy', 'med' or 'hard'")

print("Hello and Welcome to this awesome game !")
player_name = input("Please enter your name : ")
level = player_level_initialize()
keep_playing = True
usr_score = 0

while (keep_playing == True):

        num_to_guess = gen_num()
        num_of_attempts = 1
        too_m_attempts = False
        max_number_of_attempts = {
            "easy":10,
            "med":6,
            "hard":3
        }
        usr_num_guess = usr_input()

        while (too_m_attempts == False or usr_num_guess != num_to_guess):
            if (num_of_attempts < max_number_of_attempts[level]):
                try:
                    (usr_num_guess >= 1 and usr_num_guess < 100)
                except:
                    usr_num_guess = usr_input(True) # If the input number is out of range, the player gets a warning message + new input
                else:
                    if (usr_num_guess != num_to_guess):
                        if (usr_num_guess < num_to_guess):
                            print("It's more !")
                        else:
                            print("It's less !")
                        num_of_attempts += 1
                        usr_num_guess = usr_input()
                    elif (usr_num_guess == num_to_guess):
                        usr_score += 1
                        print("Good job", player_name, "you found the magic number in only", num_of_attempts, "attempts ! It was", num_to_guess, "You have a current score of", usr_score)
            else:
                print("Sorry, too many attempts ! The magic number was", num_to_guess)
                too_m_attempts = True

        keep_playing = play_again()

print("Thank you ! I hope you enjoyed the game !")
```

Comment: Why are you using `try` with a NameError exception? That `try` will catch runtime errors, not False conditions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an `if` block instead of a `try-except` block:

```
if not (usr_num_guess >= 1 and usr_num_guess < 100):
    usr_num_guess = usr_input(True) # If the input number is out of range, the player gets a warning message + new input
```

The code in the `except` part will only be executed if the line `(usr_num_guess >= 1 and usr_num_guess < 100)` raises an exception.

On the use of exception, when you write

```
try:
    ...
except:
    ...
```

the code will catch *every* possible exception and execute th code in the `except` block which is supposed to fix the situation. This is probably not what you want most of the time.  For example, mis-spelling a variable (e.g. `usr_num_guesss`) will raise a `NameError`, and whatever `user_input()` do will not fix the error -- it is an entirely different problem already than an out-of-range input. You should only catch and handle the exceptions that can be handled by your code, such as:

```
except ValueError:
    ...
```

Comment: Oh I think I understand ! So only exceptions caught by the Python debugger are returned ?